# How to determine if there is a match an return true or false in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I want to create a test that returns either true or false for email handling.

For now, if the email address starts with r+ then it's true otherwise it's false. This will help our server ignore a lot of the SPAM we are getting hit with.

Examples:

```
r+kldslkadslkadslk@site.com .. true
r+123123312@site.com .. true
vigraaaa@site.com .. FALSE
```

What's the most efficient way to handle this with Rails/ruby/regex?

Thanks

**GOAL**

Is a one liner in rails/ruby with:

```
ABORT if XXXXX == 0
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will match:

```
/^r\+.*@site.com$/
```

Examples:

```
>> 'r+kldslkadslkadslk@site.com' =~ /^r\+.*@site.com$/ #=> 0
>> 'vigraaaa@site.com' =~ /^r\+.*@site.com$/ #=> nil
```

Since everything that isn't `nil` or `false` is truthy in Ruby, you can use this regex in a condition. If you really want a boolean you can use the `!!` idiom:

```
>> !!('vigraaaa@site.com' =~ /^r\+.*@site.com$/) #=> false
>> !!('r+kldslkadslkadslk@site.com' =~ /^r\+.*@site.com$/) #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I do this in rails/ruby so it's  ABORT if XXXXX == 0

Comment: Tried your last idea, that lead to syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)

Comment: Still not able to get this working, tried if (params[:to].to_s =~ (/^r\+.*@site.com$/)) == nil

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error, I copied over from IRB, realized I forgot the anchors and then added them in the wrong position :-(

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I still get the error with: Rails.logger.info !!(params[:to] =~ /^r\+.*@site.com/$)

Comment: The `$` goes before the `/` that closes the regex (`/^r\+.*@site.com$/`).

Answer (score 11):

If you're in Rails, there's a starts_with? method on strings:

```
"foo".starts_with?('f') # => true
"foo".starts_with?('g') # => false
```

Outside of Rails, regexes are a reasonable solution:

```
"foo" =~ /^f/ # => true
"foo" =~ /^g/ # => false
```

Because Ruby uses truthiness in if statements, if you do end up using regexes, you can just use the return value to switch:

```
if "foo" =~ /^f/
  puts "Was true!"
else
  puts "Was false!"
end
```

If you're writing a method and want to return a boolean result, you could always use the double bang trick:

```
def valid_email?
  !!("foo" =~ /^f/)
end
```

Rubular (rubular.com) is a good site for testing Ruby regexes pre-1.9. (1.9's regexes added things like lookahead.)

Comment: Outside of Rails there's also a String "start_with?" (note singular).

Comment: Not sure I like the starts_with idea, it would only match r and not r+ which would be much more useful against spammers

Comment: Why couldn't you do `start_with? "r+"`? I mean, I'd use a regex too so it could match anything before a `+`, but start_with? will match whatever you give it.

Comment: Note: `start_with?` has been added to Ruby Core. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F

Comment: I think the above answer is misleading because `"foo" =~ /^f/ #=> 0` and 
`"foo" =~ /^g/ #=> nil`

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use an "!!" operator:

```ruby
!!("foo" =~ /^f/)
```

you could use a ternary operator (might look more obvious):

```ruby
"foo" =~ /^f/ ? true : false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **'===' operator** as well

```
/f/ === 'foo' #=> true

/f/ === 'bat' #=> false
```

Note: The regex part is on the left:

> /YOUR_REGEX/ === 'YOUR_STRING'

Answer (score 1):

`Regexp#match?` was added to [Ruby-2.4.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/). See [Regexp#match documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Regexp#match%3F-instance_method).

```
irb(main):001:0> "ack!".match? /a(b|c)/
=> true
irb(main):002:0> "add".match? /a(b|c)/
=> false
```